# Faster way to access 2D lists/arrays and do calculations in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, list

I am running 2 nested loops (first one 120 runs, second one 500 runs).
In most of the 120x500 runs I need to access several lists and lists-in-lists (I will call them 2D arrays).

At the moment the 120x500 runs take about 4 seconds. Most of the time is taken by the three list appends and several 2D array accesses.
The arrays are prefilled by me outside of the loops.

Here is my code:

```
    #Range from 0 to 119
    for cur_angle in range(0, __ar_angular_width-1):

        #Range from 0 to 499
        for cur_length in range(0, int(__ar_length * range_res_scale)-1):

            v_x = (auv_rot_mat_0_0*self.adjacent_dx[cur_angle][cur_length])+(auv_rot_mat_0_1*self.opposite_dy[cur_angle][cur_length])
            v_y = (auv_rot_mat_1_0*self.adjacent_dx[cur_angle][cur_length])+(auv_rot_mat_1_1*self.opposite_dy[cur_angle][cur_length])

            v_x_diff = (v_x+auv_trans_x) - ocp_grid_origin_x
            v_y_diff = (v_y+auv_trans_y) - ocp_grid_origin_y

            p_x = (m.floor(v_x_diff/ocp_grid_resolution))
            p_y = (m.floor(v_y_diff/ocp_grid_resolution))

            data_index = int(p_y * ocp_grid_width + p_x)

            if data_index >= 0 and data_index < (len(ocp_grid.data)-1):
                probability = ocp_grid.data[data_index]

                if probability == 100:
                    if not m.isnan(self.v_directions[cur_angle]):
                        magnitude = m.pow(probability, 2) * self.magnitude_ab[cur_length]

                        ov_1 = self.v_directions[cur_angle]
                        ov_2 = magnitude
                        ov_3 = self.distances[cur_length]

                        obstacle_vectors.append(ov_1)
                        obstacle_vectors.append(ov_2)
                        obstacle_vectors.append(ov_3)
```

I tried to figure out the processing times via time.time() and building differences, but it didn't work reliable. The calculated times were fluctuating quite a lot.

I am not really a Python pro, so any advices are welcome.
Any ideas how to make the code faster?

EDIT:
The initialization of the arrays was done with this code:

```
        self.adjacent_dx = [i[:] for i in [[0]*(length_iterations-1)]*(angular_iterations-1)]
        self.opposite_dy = [i[:] for i in [[0]*(length_iterations-1)]*(angular_iterations-1)]
```

Comment: Do not use `time.time()` directly to time the results. Wrap your code in a specific function and use the `timeit` module. In particular it's pretty simple to profile when using the `IPython` console and its `%timeit` magic.

Comment: Learn NumPy and use its vectorized operations.

Comment: Thanks for the quick tips. I will look into timeit. I am not sure about NumPy though, isn't it only quicker for big calculations?

Comment: For this kind of operations NumPy seems to need about 2-10 times more than python lists. I assume NumPy is only a good choice for larger and more complex operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some general tips:

1. Try to optimize your algorithm the best You can.
2. If it's possible, then use [PyPy](http://pypy.org/) instead of regular Python. This usually doesn't require any code modification if all Your external dependencies work with it.
3. Static typing and compilation to C can add additional boost, but requires some simple code modifications. For this purpose You can use [Cython](http://cython.org/).

Note that step 1 is very ofter hard to do and most time consuming, giving you small amounts of boost if you have already good code, while the steps 2 and 3 give you dramatic boost without much additional effort.

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look into these possibilities. The algorithm is already very small, so as you said it's probably the best to look at step 2 and 3.